# While extracting text from PDF file using iTextSharp, I am getting this error: “Could not find image data or EI”

Tags: c#, itext

While extracting text from PDF file using iTextSharp using the below piece of code, I am getting this error: “Could not find image data or EI” while debugging the code found that this error is coming in certain pages but not all pages, then further investigated and also found that generally there are two types image in pdf xObject image and Inline Image and using the below piece of code Inline Image ca not be handled. There are few few comments in this issue in other similar post that suggested to use latest version(5.5.0) itextsharp, that also i did but no luck. My basic purpose is to extract the text in the page not image. How can I handle the Inline image or how can I extract only the text regardless what type of image the page having.

```
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
PdfContentByte pdfData = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(page);
LocTextExtractionStrategy its = new LocTextExtractionStrategy();
pdfData = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(page);

string extractedTextInCurrentPage=PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, its);//In this line exception is throwing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please share your PDF.

This is why:

Your PDF contains an inline image. Inline images are problematic in ISO-32000-1, but I personally saw to it that the problem will be solved in ISO-32000-2 (for PDF 2.0, to be expected in 2017).

In ISO-32000-1, an inline images starts with the `BI` operator, followed by some parameters. The length of the image bytes isn't one of those parameters. The actual image bytes are enclosed by an `ID` and an `EI` operator.

Software parsing PDF syntax needs to search for these operators and usually does a good job at it: find `BI`, then take the bytes between `ID` and `EI`. However: *what to do when you encounter an image of which `EI` is part of the image bytes?*

This hardly ever happens, but it was reported to us as a problem and we solved this in recent iText versions by converting the bytes between `ID` and `EI` to an image. If that fails, iText continues searching for the next `EI`. If iText doesn't find that `EI` parameter, you get the exception you mention.

This is a cumbersome process and, being a member of the ISO committee that writes the PDF standards, I introduced a new inline image parameter into the spec: the parameter `/L` will informs parsers exactly how many bytes are to be expected between the `ID` and `EI` operators. At the same time, I saw to it that the recommendation of keeping inline images smaller than 4 KB became normative: in PDF 2.0, it will be illegal to have inline images with more than 4096 bytes. Of course: this doesn't help you. PDF 2.0 doesn't exist yet. My work in the ISO committee only helps to solve the problem on the long term.

On the short term, we've written a work-around that solves the problem for the PDFs that were reported to us, but apparently, you've found a PDF that escapes the workaround. If you want us to solve the problem, you'll have to share the PDF.